# How to turn -1.06267582739e+11 into -106267582739.0 in python?

Tags: python

How to suppress scientific notation from a float value in python. Here I tried the following code but it's not working

```
r_val[v].append('%.2f' % val.get("closing_balance"))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...You do realize that `-1.06` isn't anywhere close to `-1.06e+11`, right?

Comment: yes sorry for that but my point to remove the 'e' from the notation

Comment: So the output should be `-106267582739.0`?

Comment: Well, at least you should first get rid of the `e+11` part by multiplying by `e-11` if that's not relevant for you (python doesn't know that!).

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes correct

Comment: I only just realized... there's nothing wrong with the code you posted? `'%.2f'%-1.06267582739e+11` returns `'-106267582739.00'` as it should. What's the problem with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `format(x, '.#f')`

consider this snippet:

```
x = 0.000000235
print(x)
2.35e-07
print (format(x, '.9f'))
0.000000235
```

Or, to go closer to your question:

```
y = -1.06267582739e-11  # note I changed '+' to '-' since '+' is is just represented as a regular float

    print(y)
    -1.06267582739e-11

    print(format(y,'.22f'))
    -0.0000000000106267582739
```